# app/Console/cake vs lib/Console/cake in CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp, command-line-interface

I'm new to `Shell` using **CakePHP** and I couldn't notice how there are 2 `cake` console application: one at `app/Console/cake`  and other in `lib/Console/cake` being the second one the one in **CakePHP's core**.

So far, I have used `lib/Console/cake bake -app /path/to/app` to **bake** some **MVC** classes, but I have never used `app/Console/cake` before. Also `lib/Console/cake` is configured in my **environment variables**.

I want to know the difference of these 2, when to use one or another and why.

**Note:** I moved my core folder to a different directory, so naturally, `app/Console/cake` wont find `ShellDispatcher`, which line should I modify to set the new path to core library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are identical, but you should use the one inside app folder:

```
cd app/
./Console/cake bake
```

To change the default folder structure and config you must edit these files:

```
/app/webroot/index.php
/app/webroot/test.php
```

and un-Comment this line putting your core folder location:

```
// /usr/lib/mylocation    
define('CAKE_CORE_INCLUDE_PATH', DS . 'usr' . DS . 'lib' . DS . 'mylocation');
```

Take a look at the manual here:
http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/installation/advanced-installation.html#sharing-cakephp-libraries-with-multiple-applications

Comment: is there any reason I should use the one in the app?

Comment: Probably no. The only difference is that calling from lib/Console/cake the -app parameter is required.

Comment: @manzapanza no `-app` not required, if you are still inside the app dir (which you should always be anyway). Until recently I always just used `../lib/Cake/Console/cake [command]` - which works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

### The difference

The difference between the two executables is that [one derives the app location from the current working directory](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/master/lib/Cake/Console/cake#L38), and [the other is application specific](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/master/app/Console/cake#L38). This can be highlighted like so:

#### Normal usage:

```
www-data @ dev [ /tmp/cakephp ] (master=)
-> app/Console/cake 

Welcome to CakePHP v2.4.6 Console
---------------------------------------------------------------
App : app
Path: /tmp/cakephp/app/
---------------------------------------------------------------
```

#### Reference app executable from different path:

```
-> cd anywhere
-> /tmp/cakephp/app/Console/cake 

Welcome to CakePHP v2.4.6 Console
---------------------------------------------------------------
App : app
Path: /tmp/cakephp/app/
---------------------------------------------------------------
```

Note the app and path did not change.

#### `cake` in path

If `/tmp/cakephp/lib/Cake/Console/` is in the path:

```
-> cd anywhere
-> cake 

Welcome to CakePHP v2.4.6 Console
---------------------------------------------------------------
App : xxx
Path: **anywhere**
---------------------------------------------------------------
```

Note the app and path vary depending on where you are when executing the command.

If you always specify the `-app` flag, they will function the same, but you'll find it is problematic to use cake in your path if for example you have multiple applications on the same host using different versions of CakePHP.

### Fixing paths

If you moved the cake folder, the files you need to edit are:

- app/Console/cake.php (`$root` variable/include_path)
- app/webroot/index.php (ROOT constant)
- app/webroot/test.php (ROOT constant)

Only the first will affect cli usage.